# Angularjs - How to disable submit button if any value exceeds the ng-repeat element value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-submit, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have such type of program.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Amt" : "500",
      
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "800",
     
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1580",
    },
    {
      "Amt" : "1122",
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.value=function(d, x)
  {
    x.balance = x.Amt - d;
    if(d > x.Amt){
    $scope.isExceeded = true;
  } else {
    
    $scope.isExceeded = false;
  }  
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>Amt</td>
  <td>Balance</td> 
  <td>Entered Amt</td>
  <td ng-if="error"> Error</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in records">
  <td>{{x.Amt}}</td>
  <td>{{x.balance}}</td>
   <td><input type="text" ng-model="d" ng-change="value(d, x)"></td>  
  <td ng-if="d > x.Amt" ng-model="error">Please enter less than {{x.Amt}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input type="button" value="Submit" ng-disabled="isExceeded"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want is submit button should become disable if any Entered Amt value exceeds the Amt value.

I m not getting an idea of how can I achieve this type of condition.I an new to angularjs.

Comment: Use ng-disable directive and pass the condition

Comment: Its working now.Its what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an variable `isExceeded` and use it in the angular markup with `ng-disable` directive to disable the button.

```
<body ng-app="myApp">   
   <table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
     <tr>
       <td>Amt</td>
       <td>Balance</td> 
       <td>Entered Amt</td>
       <td ng-if="error"> Error</td>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
       <td>{{x.Amt}}</td>
       <td>{{x.balance}}</td>
       <td><input type="text" ng-model="d" ng-change="value(d, x)"></td>  
       <td ng-if="d > x.Amt" ng-model="error">Please enter less than {{x.Amt}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="4" ng-disable="isExceeded"><input type="button" value="Submit"></td>
     </tr>
   </table>    
</body>
```

and check it in the angular controller like

```
$scope.value=function(d, x)
{
  if(d > x.Amt){
    $scope.isExceeded = true;
  } else {
    x.balance = x.Amt - d;
    $scope.isExceeded = false;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ.

Comment: But isnt there is any other method to do it in html itself?

Comment: Yes there is a method, you need the current item outside the `ng-repeat`, for which you chage the value. You can store the index and then use in the html the current item. But it is more easy to do like this

Comment: can you post jsfiddle for it. @SurenSrapyan. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Anyway you need to do in both sides, in controller and in the html. Don't fear to keep an extra variable, if it will make your code more readable